# Google Map issue with loading

Tags: html, css, google-maps

I'm Looking for some help with a Google Map - I feel I've tried most fixes found via Google. One in particular suggested the parent `div (class="findus__gm--small")` needed a height and width - didn't work.

I took the code off a previous project where it worked successfully. I cannot see any differences.

Any Suggestions?

```
<div class="main-content__info"> <!-- small google map and open hours-->
                    <div class="findus__small"> 
                        <div class="findus_small_gm_text"> <!-- small google map text-->
                            <h4 class="title__marginbtm"><span class="title--underline">Where to find us</span></h4>
                            <p class="lh--200">Based in Yeadon, you can find us just off of "Kirk Lane", on the corner of "Whack House Lane". Bus stops are just a 5 minute walk away, with services running regulerally. Please note, street parking is limited. </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="findus__gm--small"> <!-- small google map-->
                            <div id="googleMap"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="openhours"> <!--open hours table -->
                    </div>
                </div>

.findus__gm--small {
    height: 10em;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 100%;
}

#googleMap {
    height: 10em;
    width: 100%;
}

    var location= new google.maps.LatLng(53.8659011,-1.6932696);
        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center:location,
                zoom:17,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({ 
                map:map,
                position:location,
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"66 Whack House Lane, Yeadon, Leeds, LS19 7LY"
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});

$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider(); 
    effect:'random'
});
```

Comment: If your trying to implement an actual google-maps you have to integrate it using an iframe provided in Google Developers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Not entirely sure how, but starting from the beginning (again) and following the Google dev tutorial seems to have fixed it.

Must have been a silly error somewhere.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you used google map's preserved keyword "Location" as variable and in order to work the google map you should  change var location to some other word. Corrected js is :-

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&#038;signed_in=true&#038;ver=4.4.1'></script>

<script>
var LatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(53.8659011,-1.6932696);
        function initialize() {
            var mapProp = {
                center:LatLng,
                zoom:17,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({ 
                map:map,
                position:LatLng
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content:"66 Whack House Lane, Yeadon, Leeds, LS19 7LY"
              });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map,marker);
              });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
```

Comment: Have you added the google map  js above the code and changed the keyword location ?